# Problems with assembler, nasm "Segmentation fault (core dumped)"

Tags: assembly, nasm

I'm having some problems when I'm running my nasm practice. I have a message saying "Segmentation fault (core dumped)" I would like to know if some would help me
I'm trying lots of things, but I dont still get to the problem.
Hope someone could help me for real haha

This is the code I have at the moment:

```
section .data
a1: dd 83
resultado: dw 0
section .text
global _start

start:
mov    ebx,a1
mov    ax,[ebx]
xor    dx,dx
push   dx
push   ax
push   dx
push   dx
push   dx
call   redon5
pop    dx
pop    dx
pop    dx
pop    dx
pop    dx
mov    ebx,resultado
mov    [ebx],dx

mov    ebx,0        ; exit code, 0=normal
mov    eax,1        ; exit command to kernel
int    0x80         ; interrupt 80 hex, call kernel

redon5:
mov    ebp,esp      ; "sincroniza" el base pointer
mov    ax,[ebp + 10] ; pone en ax el argumento "p"
mov    dx,10
div    dx           ; separa unidades de decenas (q y r)
cmp    ax,3
jge    intervalo_2
mov    word [ebp + 4],0  ; k1 = 0
mov    word [ebp + 2],0  ; k2 = 0
jmp    fin_de_if

intervalo_2:
cmp   ax,8
jge   intervalo_3
mov    word [ebp + 4],5  ; k1 = 5
mov    word [ebp + 2],0  ; k2 = 0
jmp    fin_de_if

intervalo_3:
mov    word [ebp + 4],0  ; k1 = 0
mov    word [ebp + 2],10 ; k2 = 10

fin_de_if:
mov    dx,[ebp + 10] ; vuelve a recuperar p
sub    dx,ax         ;dx <-- p - r
add    dx,[ebp + 4]  ;dx <-- (p-r) + k1
add    dx,[ebp + 2]  ;dx <-- (p-r) + k1 + k2
mov    [ebp + 8],dx  ; valor de retorno de la función
ret
```

Comment: Did you use a debugger to determine where this happens? There’s one obvious place but learning to debug, especially assembly code, is essential. And what lots of things are you trying?

Comment: no, I'm just using the commands 
nasm -f elf64 test.asm
ld test.o -o test

Comment: Then grab a debugger and run the code there to see what’s happening.

Comment: I'm having problems with it.. It's because I'm just learning how to use assembly.
I'm trying to debug it with geany

Comment: using a debugger is essential, esp when programming in assembler. you WILL need one, sooner or later (rather sooner)

Comment: I am curious, the code you have is 32-bit; why did you use `elf64`?

Comment: As I said, I’m learning assembly and I don’t have a clue

Answer (score 0):

I don't have high enough reputation to add a comment but (assuming that your use of elf64 is because you're trying to run 32-bit code on a 64-bit system) try using:

`nasm -f elf64 -g -F stabs test.asm
ld -o test test.o`

or

`nasm -f elf -g -F stabs test.asm
ld -o test test.o -melf_i386`

see about halfway down the page: http://duntemann.com/assembly.html
for some explanation.

The "-g" followed by "-F stabs" will produce output that you can use in the gdb debugger and really figure out where the seg-fault is in your program ^_^ (as Sami also indicated). Set some breakpoints and use "stepi" in gdb to find the problem.

Comment: The OP's code is using ESP/EBP not RSP/RBP, so it would truncate the stack pointer to 32 bits and segfault if built as 64-bit code.  Only your 2nd set of commands can work.  (And then the OP's code is still weird, using 16-bit stack operations.)  Your first suggestion is what the OP is already doing, according to their comment, which of course doesn't work because Linux puts the stack pointer outside the low 32 bits of address space in 64-bit processes.